# Google Sign-In gives error when swiching to secondary Youtube accounts

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-signin, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

I am currently trying to use `gapi.auth2` from Google Sign-In for Websites API and this is the code I have:

-- load the library with:

`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadGapiCallback" async defer></script>`

-- initialize an auth2 variable:

```
var auth2;

window.onLoadGapiCallback = () => {
  gapi.load('auth2', () => {
    auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
      'client_id': 'CLIENT_ID',
      'scope': 'profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'
    });
  });
};
```

-- and when a botton is clicked do:

```
auth2.signIn().then(() => {
  console.log('auth is:', auth2.currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token);
});
```

This works well, it initializes the auth2 variable, when I click the button, it shows the `SingIn` prompt and I choose one of my Google Accounts. The problem is from now on when I have to choose a YouTube account, if I choose other account than the main one, I'll get an Exception Object like this one:

```
{type: "tokenFailed", idpId: "google", error: "USER_LOGGED_OUT"}
```

also there's an XHR request being sent lastly that has this response:

```
{"error":"USER_LOGGED_OUT","detail":"No active session found."}
```

So it only works if I choose **the main account**, but I cannot choose other YouTube accounts.

What am I missing here?
I've looked into all these docs but none helped me:

[Getting profile information](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people)

[Google Sign-In JavaScript client reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference)

[Monitoring the user's session state](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/session-state)

**Update**:
Running the code from this [example](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button#building_a_button_with_a_custom_graphic) (but with this `scope`: `'profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'`) will only work if I choose the first Youtube account for each Google account. If I choose any other Youtube account, I'll get this alert error:

[image]

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @PrajeethEmanuel, unfortunately not

Comment: I have the same issue.