# Google+ Sign-In: Cannot choose secondary YouTube accounts for authorized requests

Tags: google-signin, google-authentication, google-account, youtube-data-api, google-api-js-client

In order to make a request to `Youtube Data API`'s `youtube.channels.list` with the `mine` parameter set to `true`, I have to make a properly authorized request, i.e. I need to provide a token that is bound to that channel.

In order to get that token, I use the Google client library from here:

```
<script src="//apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js"></script>
```

that enables me to make authentication requests on behalf of a certain Google account.

With this in mind, I have this code:

```
var parameters = {
  'clientid': 'CLIENT_ID',
  'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
  'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
  'include_granted_scopes': true,
  'callback': 'googleLogin'
};

gapi.auth.signIn(parameters);

...

window.googleLogin = (authResult) => {
  if (authResult[ 'error' ] == 'immediate_failed') return;

  if (authResult[ 'status' ][ 'signed_in' ]) {
    // make GET request to https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true
    // with Authorization header `Bearer ${gapi.auth.getToken().access_token}`        
  } else {
    console.log("singned out");
  }
};
```

Now the problem is that after I choose my Google Account and let's say Youtube Account no. 2, I get the results as if I had chosen the main Youtube account.

So the problem here is that the **token** that I get from `gapi.auth` doesn't consider, in any way, what Youtube account I choose and it always generates tokens for the main account (no. 1).

- I tried signing out before singing in, but doesn't do anything.
- I've also tried using gapi.auth2, but with this one I get another annoying behaviour that I've described here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951665/gapi-auth2-gives-error-when-swiching-youtube-accounts)

What's even more weird is that if I try switching between the Youtube accounts several times, it **sometimes** makes request for the correct account, so the code is correct, but still doesn't offer the desired result.

So how can I make proper authorized requests based on a certain Youtube account?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find the solution?

Comment: @StevenTrigg nope, I haven't found anything.